# Javascript: table layout is ignored when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

When I use Javascript to place some table tags on a webpage, the displayed text is ignoring the table tags. It just places the text next to each other, instead of displaying it in columns.

This picture shows what is displayed:
[image: example output]
In blue are the column headers, in black the table content. As you can see the table content does not follow the column headers...

This is the relevant piece of Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = 
  '<div class="table-row"> 
   <div class="table-cell">114</div>
   <div class="table-cell">GebouwEigenaar</div>
   <div class="table-cell">Paleis het Loo</div>
   <div class="table-cell">Begane Grond</div>
   <div class="table-cell">Koffiecorner 1</div>
   <div class="table-cell">Kantoorruimte</div>
   </div>';
```

This is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div id="searchresults"></div>
```

The CSS used to display table rows and cells is used without issues elsewhere in the webapplication. It is also used to display the column headers in this way:

```
<div class="table-row-header">
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Sticker-ID</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Gebouweigenaar</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Gebouw</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Verdieping</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Ruimte</div>
  <div class="table-cell col-2" >Ruimtefunctie</div
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.table { display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}
.table-row { display: table-row; width: 100%; cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 20px;}
.table-row:nth-child(even) { background: #fafafa; }
.table-row:nth-child(odd) { background: white; }
.table-row-header { display: table-row; width: 100%; color: #0867b3; border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7; background: white; }
.table-cell {display: table-cell; padding: 10px 10px; position: relative; }
.table-cell span { display: none; font-weight: bold; }
.col-2  { width: 16.66%; }
```

It appears that the browser does not render the HTML inserted by JavaScript.
But why that happens...?

I have tried replacing .innerHTML with .value, but that did not display anything.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What is search result?

Comment: You need to show example HTML and CSS. It is just a guessing game without it.

Comment: It appears you're using some library to format your table, not just plain CSS. You need to execute your script that adds new table rows before you execute that library so that the library finds and formats them.

Comment: The thing that's worth trying is making a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example They tend to take some time to make, but once you have one of those someone will be able to help you out fairly easily and quickly.

Comment: Updated to answer the questions listed above.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.
It was caused by an incorrect use of  table-formatting tags.
That caused the formatting to be incorrect.
Thanks everyone for the provided suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There is something that is preventing your table row and table cells from picking up their .css attributes. It's hard to guess why without knowing your .css files and surrounding context. But as a surface level guess, consider looking at

1) Your table cell/row css properties aren't being imported correctly.

2) Whether your parent table's css properties are overriding their children's properties.

As a clue, you should try pasting those divs outside the context of your table. Does the css styling automatically show up? If so, you now know that it's something to do with the parent divs. If not, you know the problem is with the child divs.